# How to track a form on submit with Google Analytics and PHP

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to track a form with GA and setup GOAL's i need a proper code that work when the form is submited.

my code is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['button'])){
  GA code here..
}

?>
```

there is difrent examples out there but, i need one thats actual work, so if anyone have example that work, im intressed in such.

Answer (score 1):

Save the google analytics script in a file say analyticstracking.php, then include the file as follows:

```
<?php   include_once("analyticstracking.php"); ?>
```

The code to be saved in analyticstracking.php can be found from google analytics site.

Comment: I need to track an event = form submit, i know how to add GA tracking script.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial answer, expanding on your own code example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['button'])){
?>
<script>
ga('send', 'event', 'Fom', 'submit', 'some label');
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Closing and opening the php tags means the code in the if condition will only be executed when the condition is met. This is a less than elegant solution, but workable (as long as the tracker is created somewhere before in the page). It would be better to create a dedicate url for a thankyou-page and track that.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the track event api 
for ga 2
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide
for universal analytics
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

If you want to do it PHP side see this https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-ga

if jquery/ js then

for ga2

```
$( "form" ).submit(function() {

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'formsubmit', 'form', 'form was submitted']);

});
```

or for universal analytics

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'form submitted');
});
```

Comment: I need a jQuery+Java script that tracking my Goal for submit form.

Comment: That .js is triggered upon form.submit. i want to be able to use my PHP code. can i run just the -> echo "<SCRIPT>ga('send', 'event', 'form', 'submit', 'form submitted');</SCRIPT>";  ?